# Isn't there a CMOS battery in Xbox 360 to preserve date&time setting?

Tags: xbox-360

Everytime a power failure occurs, the date&time setting in my Xbox 360 resets to year 2005. It's annoying because some games keep track of my progress using the date&time (e.g. Your Shape Fitness Evolved 2012). It is also bad because *save data* also records date&time and whenever I need to load a *saved data*, it shows me 2005.

Isn't there a CMOS battery in Xbox 360 to preserve the date&time setting? If there is, I'm going to suspect mine has drained. If there is not, what are my chances to preserve the date&time setting?

Note: I also use an uninterruptible power supply (UPS) with my Xbox 360 for safety, but  I have to turn it off every night just because if the electricity cuts off at night, it wakes me up with an irritating warning sound.

Comment: what area are you in that you run the risk of power failure every night?

Comment: An area in Istanbul. There are some new construction sites in the neighborhood which cause the blackouts recently. It does not happen every night, but frequent enough to bother me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the title's question, no, there is not.  Google's opinion (for instance, [the post here, waay at the bottom](http://www.biline.ca/xbox-faq.htm#loop)) is that there's only limited ability for the xbox to retain real-time date/time tracking; at best it can last 12 hours when unplugged, at worst 45 minutes.  Since you said you turn off the UPS every night I bet that's what's happening...try leaving the power connected for a night and see if it does the same thing.  Posts also abound claiming that as long as you're connected to XBL it should auto-update the time on boot.

Comment: Yes, the clock will set automatically for you when connected to Live.

Comment: 45 minutes is far from worst, mine is ~5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The Xbox 360 does not contain a CMOS battery, no.  The RTC chip on the xbox is powered solely from the power brick (which will continue to draw small amounts of energy while the box is powered down, for WoL, RTC and a few other features).

My advice would be to look into some way to turn off the warning noise on the UPC - it should be possible to turn off the noise, allowing you to get some sleep while also keeping your devices safe from power failure.